# wp search-replace inside site's directory bring PHP fatal error

Tags: fatal-error

I executed the following command in a website directory:

```
sudo wp search-replace 'http://fortheman.consulting' 'http://formen.co.il' --all-tables-with-prefix
```

This brought:

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_bloginfo() in /var/www/html/formen.co.il/wp-includes/class-wp-locale.php:233

From a quick Google search there aren't any solid solutions on this. What will you say is the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem was unchanged (or shall I say, "adjusted") wp-config.php file in the site's directory.

The DB-name and DB-username there where both outdated. I changed them to the new ones and than I ran the command successfully.